# MKCoordinateRegion doesn't display on map in the proper way

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, mapkit

I'm using the following code to make zoom out on map MKMapView .

```
float zoom=1.5;
MKCoordinateRegion region;
//Set Zoom level using Span
MKCoordinateSpan span;  
region.center=mapView.region.center;
span.latitudeDelta=mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta *zoom;
span.longitudeDelta=mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta *zoom;
region.span=span;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
```

But in the case when zoom=1.1, zoom=1.3, or zoom=1.5, the map displays  the same regian in all 3 cases. This region looks the same as when zoom=2.

How can I make display the map so that the correct region is displayed in each of these cases?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4800042/467105)

Comment: thanks !this question is the same as mine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one....

```
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

You can set `span.longitudeDelta`and `span.latitudeDelta` as how much u want to zoom-in or out...
And also initialize MKCoordinateRegion..

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }
```

Set delegate to mapView

```
[mapView setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } } ;
    region.center=mapView.region.center;
    float f1=mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta;
    float f2=mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta;
    f1=f1*1.1;
    f2=f2*1.1;       
    region.span.latitudeDelta=f1;
    region.span.longitudeDelta=f2;
   [ mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];

Comment: do you mean that I need to write this code ? in this case will be the same situation so it doesn't help. In my case "self" is already the delegate of mapView.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
MKCoordinateSpan span; 
//You can set span for how much Zoom to be display
span.latitudeDelta=.005;
span.longitudeDelta=.005;

//set Region to be display on MKMapView
MKCoordinateRegion cordinateRegion;
cordinateRegion.center=latAndLongLocation.coordinate;
//latAndLongLocation coordinates to be display 
cordinateRegion.span=span;

[mapView setRegion:cordinateRegion animated:YES];
//mapView MkMapView
```

It'll definitely work.