# MapView, how can I change the distance?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

In mapview, how can I change it from A to B as in the picture?

And here is the code:

```
#define BE_Latitude 25.9444055
#define BE_longtitude -80.1229769

#define BEMSpan 0.100f;
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSo28.jpg)

---

EDITED

Code

```
#import "BEViewController.h"
#import "BENSObject.h"

@interface BEViewController ()

@end


#define BE_Latitude 25.9444055
#define BE_longtitude -80.1229769

#define BEMSpan 0.100f;

@implementation BEViewController
@synthesize BEMapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MKCoordinateRegion BERegion;

    //Center
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = BE_Latitude;
    center.longitude = BE_longtitude;

    //Span
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = BE_Latitude;
    span.longitudeDelta = BE_longtitude;

    BERegion.center = center;
    BERegion.span = span;

    //Set our map
    [BEMapView setRegion:BERegion animated:YES];


    CLLocationCoordinate2D BELocation;
    BELocation.latitude = BE_Latitude;
    BELocation.longitude = BE_longtitude;

    BENSObject * BEAnnitation = [[BENSObject alloc] init];
    BEAnnitation.coordinate = BELocation;
    BEAnnitation.title = @“C”;
    BEAnnitation.subtitle = @“D”;


    {[self.BEMapView addAnnotation:BEAnnitation];

    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Are you sure thats all the code? Is this android or iOS, your tags are conflicting. Could you post the code where these variables are actually used

Comment: I mean distance like the picture

Comment: You want the map zoomed in? Nobody is going to be able to help you unless you post some code

Comment: I posted the entire code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724176/slight-zoom-on-mkcoordinateregion might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the zoom level you want to adjust your MKCoordinateSpan. [Apple Docs on MapKit Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MKCoordinateSpan) will help here.

You are currently using your location coordinates for the latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta.